# What are the indestructible materials in DC Universe?

Tags: dc, metamaterials

The strongest materials in the Marvel universe are [Vibranium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibranium?wprov=sfla1) and [Adamantium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium?wprov=sfla1). In the Star Wars universe there is [Cortosis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cortosis), with a special resistance against energy weapons like blasters and lightsabers. There is [Unobtainium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium) light, strong at high temperatures, and resistant to radiation damage.

**What is the strongest material in DC?**

Comment: Cortosis isn't indestructible, and is described as being relatively brittle, but has a special resistance against energy weapons like blasters and lightsabers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I did some checking, and I came up with a few possibilities.

#### Inertron

The first one I found is called [Inertron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertron), which is described on Wikipedia as the "the hardest, densest substance in the DC universe."

#### Supermanium

Another choice would be "[Supermanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermobile)", which is apparently the substance used to craft Superman's Supermobile aircraft.  It apparently is vulnerable only to one of Superman's power.

> a metal so strong that "only Superman's heat vision can soften the substance, and only his super-strength is mighty enough to mold it!"

#### Nth Metal

Finally, there is [Nth metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_metal), a magical metal used by Hawkgirl and Hawkman. It's not clear how physically durable/resistant the metal is, but it does imbue the wearer with tremendous powers. It seems reasonable to assume that it is an extremely strong substance as well.

Comment: Inertron is also the least mobile of the Transformers

Comment: I thought the hardest, densest material in the DC universe was Guy Gardener's skull...

Comment: More correctly, Supermanium is the material used to build the Supermobile - Superman "powers" the craft himself.  It's essentially a ship-shaped suit of armor that is proof to red sun radiation and Kryptonite. While Inertron is highly study, it is not completely indestructible - Matter-Eater Lad can eat it, and Karate Kid has been able to break it.

Comment: [Question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152628/wait-does-supermans-heat-vision-generate-superheat)

Answer (score 5):

[**Promethium**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Promethium), in its depleted form, forms a nearly indestructible metal when alloyed with titanium and vanadium. The pre-Rebirth Cyborg (Victor Stone)'s robot parts were made of depleted Promethium alloy. That may no longer me the case now - his armor now contains Apokoliptian / Mother Box technology that may even exceed that metal's strength.

Comment: Link - http://www.cbr.com/the-16-strongest-metals-in-comics/

Answer (score 1):

Superman (in [World's Finest #41](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_41)) creates a new element by applying heat and pressure to an ore. It's named [***Supermanium***](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Supermanium) in his honour and is described as '*the hardest substance in existence*'.

[image]

This is backed up in [Superman #167](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_167), where it's described by Brainiac (who's pretty smart) as '*the strongest **metal** known to science*'.

[image]

Interestingly, in [Superman #365](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_365), Superman himself describes it as the '*densest*' metal known, so it's apparently both the densest *and* strongest.

[image]

---

Honourable mention #1 goes to [**Amazonium**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Amazonium), also described by Diana (in [Wonder Woman #52](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_52)) as the '*hardest metal known*'.

[image]

and by the narrator in similarly glowing terms in [Wonder Woman #68](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_68).

[image]

---

Honourable mention #2 goes to ***[Marvelium](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Marvelium)***, created by Captain Marvel in [Captain Marvel Adventures #100](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Marvel_Adventures_Vol_1_100). Much like Supermanium, it's created by crushing other elements to make the '*heaviest and strongest element of all*'.

[image]

---

Honourable(ish) mention #3 goes to Inertron, a metal created by Brainiac 5 in [Adventure Comics #336](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Adventure_Comics_Vol_1_336) that is supposedly "*the most indestructible substance in the galaxy*". It loses points because it gets destructed ***repeatedly***, by Karate Kid, Superboy, Element Lad, Mon-El and various others over the next few decades.

[image]