# What is the strongest metal in the DC universe?

Tags: dc

Vibranium/Adamantium are two of the most powerful metals in the Marvel universe. Similarly, what is the strongest metal in the DC universe?
Answers from the comics, animated and live-action movies/shows are acceptable.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152422/what-are-the-indestructible-materials-in-dc-universe, although this asks about metals rather than materials.

Comment: Fans of the Washington, DC music scene might have misinterpreted this title for a moment ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Superman (in [World's Finest #41](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/World%27s_Finest_Vol_1_41)) creates a new element by applying heat and pressure to an ore. It's named [***Supermanium***](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Supermanium) in his honour and is described as '*the hardest substance in existence*'.

[image]

This is backed up in [Superman #167](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_167), where it's described by Brainiac (who's pretty smart) as '*the strongest **metal** known to science*'.

[image]

Interestingly, in [Superman #365](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_365), Superman himself describes it as the '*densest*' metal known, so it's apparently both the densest *and* strongest.

[image]

---

Honourable mention #1 goes to [**Amazonium**](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Amazonium), also described by Diana (in [Wonder Woman #52](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_52)) as the '*hardest metal known*'.

[image]

and by the narrator in similarly glowing terms in [Wonder Woman #68](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_68).

[image]

---

Honourable mention #2 goes to ***[Marvelium](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Marvelium)***, created by Captain Marvel in [Captain Marvel Adventures #100](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Marvel_Adventures_Vol_1_100). Much like Supermanium, it's created by crushing other elements to make the '*heaviest and strongest element of all*'.

[image]

---

Honourable(ish) mention #3 goes to Inertron, a metal created by Brainiac 5 in [Adventure Comics #336](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Adventure_Comics_Vol_1_336) that is supposedly "*the most indestructible substance in the galaxy*". It loses points because it gets destructed ***repeatedly***, by Karate Kid, Superboy, Element Lad, Mon-El and various others over the next few decades.

[image]

Comment: Is there an Aquamanium?

Comment: @SDH - He talks to fish, dude. If he used all of his powers he might be able to make the world's most delicious seafood platter

Comment: @SDH - There's a *Batmanium* if that makes you feel better.

Comment: That leads to an interesting question: Does Aquaman use his 'seafood platter' powers to feed himself?

Comment: @Valorum - So you're saying best superhero ever?

Comment: @T.E.D. - They keep retconning him with ever more fantastical [grab-bag powers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ComboPlatterPowers) in an attempt to make him seem less ridiculous. Now he can fly. Now he has super-strength, now he can keep up with the Flash.

Comment: @Valorum - Honestly, don't need any of that if you can come up with the world's best seafood platter. Its right there for them...

Answer (score 9):

There are several metals which have been described as unbreakable, indestructible, or the hardest or strongest in the DCU at one time or another.

As noted in [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/264760/122024), you have **[Supermanium](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Supermanium)**, **[Amazonium](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Amazonium)**, **[Marvelium](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Marvelium)**, and **[Inertron](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Inertron)** (a metal newly-discovered in the 30th century), all of which existed in the [Pre-Crisis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Pre-Crisis) era of DC comics.

---

Additionally, **[Promethium](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Promethium)** was introduced late in the Pre-Crisis era, but also exists in the later [Post-Crisis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Post-Crisis) continuity, and the current [Prime Earth](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Prime_Earth) continuity as well.

> VERNON QUESTOR: Promethium-coated metal... creating a virtually indestructible car to eliminate accidents.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #9](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_1_9)* (July, 1981)</sub>

In a DC/Marvel crossover series, Promethium was cited as a DCU counterpart to Adamantium.

> ACCESS: Whoa--nice job! Wonderful, even! And that's one tough length of lariat you got there! What is it--Adamantium?
>
> WONDER WOMAN: Enchanted. I've never head of this--Adamantium.
>
> ACCESS: Indestructible metal. Doesn't exist in your universe--but you've got Promethium, so it kind of evens out.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Unlimited Access #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Unlimited_Access_Vol_1_1)* (December, 1997)</sub>

---

In the Post-Crisis continuity, the term 'Amazonium' wasn't in use, and Wonder Woman's bracelets were simply said to have been created from the remains of Zeus' Aegis shield, formed from the hide of the Great Goat Amaltheia.

> POSEIDON: Those trinkets were once part of Zeus' mighty Aegis itself... the impenetrable shield formed from the hide of the Great Goat Amaltheia, who wet-nursed the infant Zeus and thus provided the energy from which Olympus sprung. Only two beings were ever able to violate the power of the Aegis.
>
> ZEUS: Aye, it was our father, Cronus who splintered the shield as he smote it with his final blow. When I bequeathed the shield to my daughter, Athena, she, unbeknownst to me, had Hephaestus reforge the loose fragments... into a great prize to be awarded to the mightiest and worthiest of all her Amazons. And it was Ares who long ago demolished the Aegis. Your bracelets are all that remain of that.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Wonder Woman Vol. 2 #21](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_2_21)* (October, 1988)</sub>

---

In the current Prime Earth continuity, **Kerenthium Steel** was purported to be the strongest metal in the universe, but was broken by Superman.

> Your chains were forged under the pressure of an inverted black hole. The only way to manipulate Kerenthium Steel -- the strongest metal in the universe. These chains are used to haul stars between galaxies.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Superman: Up in the Sky #6](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman:_Up_in_the_Sky_Vol_1_6)* (February, 2020)</sub>

Comment: yeah thats the problem, many metals have been credited as the strongest so theres no defenitive strongest metal

Comment: Yup. Same thing applies in Marvel, really. Marvel has never officially clarified whether True Adamantium is stronger than enhanted uru, or vice versa, for example. It has been specified that Captain America's shield is stronger than True Adamantium, but is it stronger than the Destroyer armour? I don't believe that's ever been made clear.

Comment: How does one haul a star with a chain? No matter how durable it is, a star is made of plasma. The chain would just go right through it, right? Maybe they could be hooked in the dense core and the sun could be dragged kind of slowly?

Comment: @Adamant - In the wacky world of superhero comics, who knows? There could be other factors that weren't mentioned, like force fields. We have seen _planets_ towed by chains, and while planets are pretty solid from our POV, they might as well be made from toothpaste from the POV of someone strong enough to tow a dozen or more of them at once, as the Silver Age Superboy once did.

Comment: Inertron has been broken a whole bunch of times. And not even by the likes of  Superman or Captain Marvel.

Comment: We need a Lordoftheringium - one metal to best them all!

Comment: @Valorum - If the Element Lad example you mentioned is the one I'm thinking of, it's not that bad. He just transmuted Inertron, rather than damaging it with sheer force, and it was suggested that he was able to penetrate it more quickly than Superboy, Ultraboy, and others working in concert. Also, Adamantium can be reshaped by matter-rearrangement technology and Magneto's powers, so it'd likely be just as susceptible to Element Lad's powers. As for Karate Kid, he shattered the Emerald Empress' Emerald Eye with a single blow, which is something Superboy failed to do in the same issue.

Comment: @Adamant of yourse you build some kind of container first, then connect the container to the chain.

Comment: Promethium is a *real* metallic element with atomic number 61: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promethium

Comment: @abligh - Yes, the element is briefly mentioned in [one of the comic pages I provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtltv.jpg). However, the 'Project: Promethium' discussed in said image is _not_ the element.